# Does OpenJDK 1.8 support JFR?

Tags: performance, profiling, java

I'm not sure if `OpenJDK` 1.8 supports `JFR` (java flight recorder). I know it was requested on the `OpenJDK` bugs forum.

Using `OpenJDK` on `Linux` and executing the following from a terminal:

```
jcmd `<pid>` JFR.start
```

returns

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown diagnostic command

Answer (score 7):

The OpenJDK 8 source code does not include the Java Flight Recorder implementation. That feature has been targeted to become part of OpenJDK source code with JDK 11, per http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/11/ .

Comment: This might have been true when this answer was created. But it has been backported to OpenJdk 8, as mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 7):

Officially, JFR was included in OpenJDK 8 update 262. You can check the [release notes for openjdk8u262](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2020-July/012143.html).

> New features - [JDK-8223147](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223147): JFR Backport

You can download this (or latest with JFR) release from the [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot).

Answer (score 5):

Java Flight Recorder is a commercial product included in Java SE Advanced that is only included in the Oracle JDK and not in OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks @Ingo - i had the same feeling - when I started getting the exception  - after looking at OpenJDK bug forum - there were some tickets created to support JFR.  But not sure how far that effort went.

Comment: so what are the options for OpenJDK if one needs to profile a JVM process.

Comment: All other commercial profilers support OpenJDK. My company develops JProfiler, so you could have a look at that: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Comment: Does your tool work for remote JVMS ?  Or does one need to specify an JMX port and then execute the program with the specified port in order for the tool to connect ?

Comment: No JMX is required for remote profiling, You can either make a direct connection or use the built-in SSH functionality, see http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2017/03/zero-configuration-remote-attach.htm

Comment: ok - is the tool only cognizant of jvm processes ? what if i had a child jvm process and wanted to profile it - however the OS only shows me the parent process which may be a C process.

Comment: It does not matter how a JVM has been created, it can always be profiled.

Comment: Tool should allow me to specify the user under which it should run - instead of me having to do that via terminal.   Especially for profiling a remote process which might be running under a different user.    I'm noticing that it only sees JVM processes as listed by Jpenable.   What if the JVM was created by a non-JMV parent process ? Such as a web server.   Used GUI tool to monitor remote process it gets hung on the following:  "Auto-detecting remote platform"  Is there anyway to enable logging  so I can get more details as opposed to this vague message.

Comment: You can run jpenable as that user. If it hangs at that point, the SSH connection hangs. Anything in $TMP/jprofiler_error.log on the machine where the JProfiler UI is running?

Comment: "It does not matter how a JVM has been created, it can always be profiled" -you're tool only sees JVM process.   If JVM is created by another process it does not reveal it.  What if I have a C program that as a result creates a JVM process - running jpenable does NOT reveal it.

Comment: No, that's not correct. The JVM is always created by a C program via JNI, i.e. the Java launcher. For example, JVMs created by install4j launchers can be attached to as well. If you cannot attach, it's a user or a rights issue.

Comment: Ingo - I was referring to an independent C program (outside of the JNI) that I'm using which creates a JVM process.  But jpenable does not list this process.

Comment: How does that program create the JVM if not via JNI?

Comment: yes - C program uses JNI  -  JNI_VERSION_1_6;   You can write a simple C program to initialize a JVM and it will create it given java is installed.  Does your tool utilize jcmd to get a list of all JVM processes ?  If that is the case indeed - then you maybe precluding it.

Comment: No, it uses the attach API in the JVM. For example, Windows launchers generated with install4j are also C programs that initialize the JVM via JNI and they do show up in list of attachable JVM processes. The discovery process of the attach API is somewhat brittle and uses the temporary directory, if that is set different for the process, it will not be seen by the attach API.

Comment: sounds like a limitation of the JVM

Comment: It's a little inconvenient, but if the temporary directory is not modified and the profiled JVM and the attaching process are started by the same user, it generally works.

Comment: Flight Recorder is being open sourced. http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328

Answer (score 4):

Java flight recorder is not a part of 8th version but has to be open-sourced and included in 11th release according to 
http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/328 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8193393

Update(it's there):
https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/announce/2018-September/000257.html

Answer (score 2):

Available in OpenJDK 8u262.

- New features

  - JDK-8223147: JFR Backport
    https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2020-July/012143.html

Answer (score 1):

Per http://hirt.se/blog/?p=1161 the [JFR Backport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8230764) to OpenJDK 8 is officially planned and already available to try in some builds: https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/02/jfr-coming-to-openjdk-8/