# JDK flight recorder backport in RedHat OpenJDK 8

Tags: jfr, redhat-openjdk, openjdk-8

I would like to ask, if anybody knows date or more informations about JDK flight recorder backport in the RedHat OpenJDK 8 production release (for RHEL 7)? I've tried the last build (1.8.0_242-b08) that doesn't contain it yet, and based on this article (https://www.i-programmer.info/news/80-java/13279-openjdk-8-to-get-jdk-flight-recorder.html) I thought that it will contain and nowhere can not find more information. Best regards and thanks for your answers.

Comment: FYI, Azul Systems back-ported Flight Recorder and Mission Control to Java 8. See [announcement 2019-06](https://www.azul.com/press_release/azul-systems-announces-general-availability-zulu-mission-control-v7-0/).

Comment: Possibly some useful links in https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JMC-6554

Comment: Related: [Does OpenJDK 1.8 support JFR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845964/does-openjdk-1-8-support-jfr/61185092#61185092)

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your answers. I also got answers directly from Red Hat: We plan to release Java Flight Recorder / Mission Control for OpenJDK 8 for Q3 2020 (July 2020). Have a nice day

Comment: do you know where they will publish this information? Besides your answer I did not find anything useful in the internet.

Comment: Maybe here: https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/java-1.8.0-openjdk/1.8.0.252.b09-2.el8_1/x86_64/fd431d51/package-changelog

Comment: This link would help anyone get started: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/03/15/jdk-mission-control-red-hat-build-openjdk/

Answer (score 0):

Officially, JFR was included in OpenJDK 8 update 262. You can check the [release notes for openjdk8u262](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk8u-dev/2020-July/012143.html).

> New features - [JDK-8223147](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223147): JFR Backport

You can download this (or latest with JFR) release from the [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/index.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot). I have seen that the download list included a version built by Redhat on their platform. You may have to look at the archives if you are very particular about getting one built by Redhat.